# Events in FreeRTOS 7.1.1

Tags: c, rtos, freertos

I'm looking for method how to inform one task in firmware about change somewhere else (Using FreeRTOS 7.1.1). I need to receive information about changes, but I wouldn't want check value in cycle - something like interrupts, but coming internal.

For example (in C-like pseudocode)

```
void task1(int change1)
{
 int value1 = change1;
}

void task2(int change2)
{
 int value2 = change2;
}

void task3(int change3)
{
 int value3 = change3;
}

void taskCheck()
{
  doSomething();
}
```

And when any value in any task is changed, `taskCheck()` is activated.

I thought about queues, but I prefered to ask first if there is no better solution.

P.S. There is no Event Bits and Event Group in FreeRTOS 7.1.1

Comment: Why can you not upgrade to the latest version of FreeRTOS, where you may have the option of using [direct to task notifications](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-notifications.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a semaphore to signal an event.  If the event is generic to `taskCheck` and there is no data associated with the event then you might do it something like this.

```
void task1(int change1)
{
 int value1 = change1;
 xSemaphoreGive(the_semaphore);
}

void task2(int change2)
{
 int value2 = change2;
 xSemaphoreGive(the_semaphore);
}

void task3(int change3)
{
 int value3 = change3;
 xSemaphoreGive(the_semaphore);
}

void taskCheck()
{
  xSemaphoreTake(the_semaphore, WAIT_FOREVER);
  doSomething();
}
```

If `the_semaphore` is a counting semaphore then multiple events could stack up while `taskCheck` handles them one at a time.

But if the events are specific or contain data then you probably want to use a queue instead of a semaphore.

Read about FreeRTOS queues and semaphores [here](http://www.freertos.org/Inter-Task-Communication.html).